# Python 3D matrix computation

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, matrix

I have 2 3D images of shapes 240*240*155 each. Let's call these images as i1 and i2.
I have to check for non-zero pixels of i1 and get the corresponding pixels of i2. If I do this using 3 for loops, it's taking forever. 
What is the efficient way to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: might be worth trying [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) and doing the absolute difference between the two 3D matrices

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about numpy syntax, but you can probably do something like `i2[i1 != 0]`.